Checkbox alternating between first and third state of appearance
When clicking on the first checkbox its appearance alternate between first and second states.
When clicking on any of the three checkboxes in the row they alternate between three states of appearance.
I want the checkbox to alternate between first and third appearance (skipping the second state).
Checkbox[]
Checkbox[#, {1, 2, 3}] & /@ Range[3]




I am not really sure what the UX purpose of this is, since you want to toggle between the "false (unchecked)" and "indeterminate" state, but here is a solution anyways ...
DynamicModule[{x}, Checkbox[Dynamic[x, (x = If[# == 2, 3, #]) &], {1, 2, 3}]]

Alternatively, you can use a Toggler either with a very smart workaround you've found below in the comments:
Toggler[1, {1 -> Checkbox[1, {1, 2, 3}], 2 -> Checkbox[3, {1, 2, 3}]}]

or as the last resort using customly defined buttons:
c1 = Graphics[{EdgeForm[{Thin, Black}], White, 
    Rectangle[RoundingRadius -> .2]}, ImageSize -> 15, ImagePadding -> 1];
c2 = Graphics[{EdgeForm[{Thin, Black}], LightBlue, 
    Rectangle[RoundingRadius -> .2]}, ImageSize -> 15, ImagePadding -> 1];

Toggler[1, {1 -> c1, 2 -> c2}]



I do not care about value but about appearance. Checkbox[Dynamic[x, (x = If[# == 2, 3, #]) &], {1, 2, 3}] without DynamicModule seems to be enough though.

Also is it possible without any dynamic?

(1) My comment was not about the value, but about the meaning of these states in the user interface. (2) Omitting DynamicModule, which is a scoping construct, works as long as you don't use x somewhere else in the code. (3) Not sure what you mean with "without any dynamic", and why Dynamic bothers you.

Like Checkbox[] does not need any dynamic to be able to alternate between two states by clicking on it. I would prefer the same but with first and third appearance. Documentation on Checkbox is poor, there is even no examples on values the option BaseStyle can take.

It's probably not possible, since this classic UI elements are tightly connected to the FrontEnd-OS interactions ... Have you tough about using a Toggler with a fully customized appearance? For example: Toggler[1, {1 -> Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], White, Rectangle[]}, ImageSize -> 10], 2 -> Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], Blue, Rectangle[]}, ImageSize -> 10]}]

Togler looks ugly for some reason in grid Table[Toggler[    1, {1 ->       Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], White, Rectangle[]}, ImageSize -> 10],      2 -> Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], Black, Rectangle[]},        ImageSize -> 10]}], 10, 10] // Grid - edges are not of the same thickness.

But Toggler[1, {1 -> Checkbox[1, {1, 2, 3}], 2 -> Checkbox[3, {1, 2, 3}]}] do the job and without any dynamics and also looks good in grid. Add it to your answer and I will accept it.
